# Location.speed crashes my app

Tags: ios

I am writing an app that displays's a user's latitude, longitude, altitude, speed, course, and more. Everything displays right except for the user's speed. This is my code:

```
import UIKit

import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var latitudeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var longitudeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var courseLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var speedLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var altitudeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var adressLabel: UILabel!

    var manager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        manager.delegate = self
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()

    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        let location = locations[0]
        self.latitudeLabel.text = String(location.coordinate.latitude)
        self.longitudeLabel.text = String(location.coordinate.longitude)
        self.courseLabel.text = String(location.course)
        self.speedLabel.text = String(location.speed)
        self.altitudeLabel.text = String(location.altitude)
        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { (placemarks, error) in

            if error != nil {
                print(error)
            } else {
                if let placemark = placemarks?[0] {

                    var adress = ""

                    if placemark.subThoroughfare != nil {
                        adress += placemark.subThoroughfare! + " "
                    }
                    if placemark.thoroughfare != nil {
                        adress += placemark.thoroughfare! + "\n"
                    }
                    if placemark.subLocality != nil {
                        adress += placemark.subLocality! + "\n"
                    }
                    if placemark.postalCode != nil {
                        adress += placemark.postalCode! + "\n"
                    }
                    if placemark.subAdministrativeArea != nil {
                        adress += placemark.subAdministrativeArea! + "\n"
                    }
                    if placemark.country != nil {
                        adress += placemark.country! + "\n"
                    }
                    self.adressLabel.text = adress.replacingOccurrences(of: "I-280 N", with: "")
                    print(adress.replacingOccurrences(of: "I-280 N", with: ""))

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the app the line with "self.speedLabel.text = String(location.speed)" gives me a bad instruction error with "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". I don't understand why the location.speed is not giving me a value. Then I tried:

```
if let speed = location.speed {
    self.speedLabel.text = String(speed)
}
```

But then Xcode tells me I can not use an if let statement without an optional value. The thing is, the error that I got without the if let told me location.speed is an optional, so why can't I use it in an if let. Can anyone please tell me what is wrong with my code or possibly what I could be doing wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Check the outlet connection for your label `speedLabel` also `speed` property of `CLLocation` is `non-optional` property not the `optional` one.

Comment: The error may be saying that String(location.speed) is optional, not necessarily location.speed

Comment: That worked, thanks

Comment: @tj75467 Means the problem is with outlet connection right?

Comment: Yes, it was because of an outlet

Comment: I think I renamed it or something

Comment: Also thanks Scott for trying to help